# Installation of pywin package returns error 403

Tags: python, pywin

I tried to install `pywin` by (`easy_install pywin`) and (`pip install pywin`). In both cases I got an `Error 403`, SSL is required.

Tried to google but nothing found. What could you recommend, please?

Comment: You can't use pywin32?

Comment: You can try from source: https://pypi.org/project/pywin/